# using single nginx server to serve/proxy PHP, Python and NodeJS

Tags: nginx

I am trying to figure out how best to use Nginx as proxy for serving PHP (via PHP5-FPM), Python (via gunicorn) and NodeJS.  My current default file in the sites-available directory is copied below.  Should I be attempting to configure multiple servers or make other changes in order to enable this functionality?  Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
 Currently, with the current config, Nginx is serving as a proxy to NodeJS application.  However, it is no longer serving PHP content anymore.  Should I be using a different server in the default file and if so, should I be able to use the same listening port but just use a different server_name and use the location tag to differentiate between the requests?

I am trying to route certain URL requests to a PHP application (in /var/www - I switched from /usr/share/nginx) as well as to Python and Nodejs backends.

One thought that I have not implemented is to try multiple upstream and have the PHP setup in the main server - would that work i.e. have one upstream for NodeJS, one for Python and then the server for PHP.

```
upstream test {
        server 0.0.0.0:3002;
        keepalive 500;
}


server {
        listen 81 default_server;
        listen [::]:81 default_server; ##remove this?

        root /var/www/;  ##switched from /usr/share/nginx
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost; 

        location / {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3002;
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
        location /RequestDenied {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4242;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
server {
        listen 82;
        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name php;
        location ~ /testPHP {    //testPHP is part of URL/directory name in /var/www/
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Comment: What does that mean? "it is no longer serving PHP content anymore"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this was the best way of approaching but it helped me achieve what I wanted.  I simply created a new server setup for the proxy and used one server for serving php content.

```
upstream test {
        server 0.0.0.0:3002;
        keepalive 500;
}


server {
        listen 81 default_server;
        listen [::]:81 default_server; ##remove this?

        root /var/www/;  ##switched from /usr/share/nginx
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost; 

        location / {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3002;
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
        location /RequestDenied {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4242;
        }
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
server {
        listen 82;
        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name php;

        location / {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a similar solution, serving PHP using FastCGI in Nginx along with a NodeJS server. However I wanted serve all requests from the same domain and port. I settled for proxying requests based on location instead of having a separate servers.

This example uses upstream:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 max_fails=0;
}

server {     
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    set $root /var/www/sitename;
    root $root;
    index.php index index.html;

    access_log /var/www/sitename/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/sitename/logs/error.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
            break;
        }
    }

    location /nodejs/ {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header Host $host ;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ;
    }
}
```

I found this write up useful and this code is more a less a clone:

http://blog.i-evaluation.com/2013/04/05/lannn-setting-up-nginx-with-php-and-node-js-on-aws/